# Swift 3: Converting numeric string to Bool, getting false for invalid values

Tags: swift, expression

I have to convert strings usually containing an integer number into values of type `Bool`. The rule would be to get `true` or any non-zero value. But invalid numbers shall lead to `false`.

If the strings were always valid numbers, the code would be like this:

```
let stringValue = "1"
let boolValue = Int(stringValue) != 0
```

However, that doesn't work if `stringValue` is empty, because then the `Int()` function returns `nil`, and that is unequal to 0, thus the result ends up being `true` when I want `false`.

What's an *elegant* way to solve this in Swift 3? I like to avoid extra lines with `if` clauses.

*Note: If the string could only contain "1" for `true` values, testing for `== 1` would be the answer. But I like to allow other non-zero values for `true` as well. In other words, I like to have any valid number other than 0 become `true`.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For that you can use [`Nil-Coalescing Operator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72).

```
let boolValue = (Int(stringValue) ?? 0) != 0
```

Comment: Ah, wow. I had not known about that operator. I should really make the effort and read the entire Swift 3 spec instead of learning by doing :) (There's so much to do and so little time, though!)